# alarm service android not working

Tags: java, android

so im trying to set a scheduled alarm in my android app. so the setting alarm service is here below. please tell me if its correct or not since it isnt working.

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60, alarmIntent);
```

This above is in the main method. Now i created a reciever class

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
        minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
    }
}
```

This doesnt work. Why
I want the onReceive to run every minute. Is the code fine?

Comment: What is "the main method"?  That doesn't make any sense in Android.  Android does not have a main like Java apps do.  What exactly "does not work"?  What actually happens?

Comment: What does not work is that the str is supposed to get updated and applied. apply meaning change the password. it doesnt change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `receiver` within your `AndroidManifext.xml` to receive the alarms.

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
        ...
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hey.
it does work but right then i get a FC where the error is
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.todaysfuture.dynpin.MainActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver has no zero argument constructor

Comment: I think that's caused by your MyBroadcastReceiver being within your MainActivity class.  They should be seperate files/classes.

Comment: Hey,
Yes it is in the MainActivity class
how do i put that in another class? i tried to put the MyBroadcastReceiver in another class named that only but then it cant find the minochaDevicePolicyManager
how to do it? like i need this class to be linked to the main

Comment: This is going beyond the original alarm receiver question.  You are doing the right thing putting it in a seperate file/class but now you need to create an application level singleton that both MainActivity and the MyBroadcastReceiver can use to see the miochaDevicePolicyManager.  There are many examples of this but a good starting point might be http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: Sorry I can't help directly.  Give the application class a try and if you get stuck post another question about that specifically.